# Sidekiq in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, sidekiq

I have a longstanding project that is using sidekiq with redis and a problem that has started I believe only since upgrading to sidekiq 3+.

The problem is that I can't run my rails (4.1.4) app in development without first starting a redis server.  I get the same error starting the rails server as I get when I try to run bundle exec sidekiq without first starting redis.  Running my rails app without redis running was never a problem before, even though sidekiq was setup the same way.

Can someone suggest a way around having to start a redis server even when I don't intend to run sidekiq?

Here is the backtrace:

/Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:309:in

> `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on
>   127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)     from /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:304:in`
>   establish_connection'    from
>   /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:85:in
>   `block in connect'    from
>   /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:266:in`
>   with_reconnect'  from
>   /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:84:in
>   `connect'     from
>   /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:326:in`
>   ensure_connected'    from
>   /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:197:in
>   `block in process'    from
>   /Users/mark/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:279:in`
>   logging'     from

Comment: The backtrace for the error should show where the error is occurring. Please update your question with the relevant error and backtrace.

Comment: Ok I added the backtrace.

Comment: It looks like it is trying to connect to Sidekiq in the `recurrence` block in `pnm_tournament_updater`.  What's in that block?

Comment: `recurrence backfill: true do
    daily.hour_of_day(18)
  end`

Comment: I think this problem is related to https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq/issues/103. Unfortunately, the fix has not been pulled into the main repo yet. You can try using the fixed fork in your Gemfile with `gem 'sidetiq', github: 'nkondratyev/sidetiq', branch: 'fix_working_with_prefork_servers'` to see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks @infused.  Nice find.  If you want to turn your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I've added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is related to https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq/issues/103.

Unfortunately, the fix has not been pulled into the main repo yet. You can try using the fixed fork in your Gemfile to see if it fixes the problem:

```
gem 'sidetiq', github: 'nkondratyev/sidetiq', branch: 'fix_working_with_prefork_servers'
```